# How can I convert all video type to flv video type by using ffmpeg in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ffmpeg

This is part of  my C# code.

> ```
>  if (fileExt != ".flv") {// file extension 
>  string SaveADDConvertVideo = Server.MapPath("~/videoFile/Video/") + filename;
> ```
>
> ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments = " -i " + video + " -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f flv -s                                                                                320×240 " + SaveADDConvertVideo + ".flv";
>
> ```
>   ffmpeg.StartInfo.FileName = Server.MapPath("ffmpeg.exe");
>   ffmpeg.Start();
> ```
>
> }

I want to convert any video format to .flv format.
But this code doesn't work.
I also debug my code very well and there isn't any error.
Can any one help me?
Tq very much :)

Comment: Is there any body to help me?!

Comment: Did you try the ffmpeg command itself first? Did it work?

Comment: Also what error are you getting. A full output dump would help

Comment: Dear Lord I will try by command line. Its good idea tq. I will tell thee result.

Comment: Dear Av501 I dont receive any error. Maybe there is a error when the ffmpeg.exe is runned inside my code.